# Headers Weirdly Refreshed with fetch-api in Redux-Thunk

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch-api, redux-thunk

Hi I just came accross a problem that I don't fully understand.

My API hands a new Auth-Token to my clients at every request, to be used at the next request and get a new one once again. But there is a little twist: requests sent in a short time period (within a few seconds) will be considered batch, and all those request can and have to use the same Token, because the API won't give a new Token for those.

What's weird is all the batch resquests responses DO NOT contain a new Token, but my client app still managed, somehow, to refresh it's state with old and expired Tokens...

Here's what I do:
At every successful request, I dispatch a "REFRESH-TOKEN" action that gets the new information from the response headers like so:

```
let accessToken = response.headers.get("Access-Token")
let expiry = response.headers.get("Expiry")
dispatch(refreshTokens({
    status: "loggedIn",
    accessToken: accessToken,
    expiry: expiry
}));
```

`response` comes from the fetch-api, and it seems to me that it gives me expired responses when the headers aren't present.

Many thanks to whoever can explain to me what happens. Right now my unsatisfying solution was to turn-off the batch request feature.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to narrow down the issue based on the snippet you shared but I recommend the following things:

1. Use [redux-devtools](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools) to inspect occurred actions and how they affect your state.
2. Consider using [redux middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) to update accessToken and expiry date. Your use case fits it very well. Actions should reflect user interaction, which refreshToken is not.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting redux middleware, I skipped looking into this.. And yeah I did integrate devTools later on, but couldn't get anymore clues out of it, the `REFRESH_TOKEN` action (dispatched in the thunk) just somehow carries expired tokens...